# How to use angularjs ng-click with html5 datalist

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, html-datalist

I'm working with AngularJS and i want to use the directive `ng-click` when an element of a datalist (html5) is selected.

Here is an example of my actual code:

```
<label>Search</label>
<input type="text" class="input-search" list="datalistcit" ng-change="changeQuery(queryCity)" ng-model="queryCity" />
<datalist id="datalistcit">
   <option ng-repeat="city in cities" ng-click="goCity(city)" value="{{city.name}}">
   </option>
</datalist>
```

It doesn't work, never execute the js method goCity.. any idea?

Comment: You probably need an ng-model in your datalist. I know that it wouldn't work if it were a select tag without an ng-model.

Comment: not work..
here is en example http://jsfiddle.net/lukers/MCnL2/

Comment: Try my answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112662/html-datalist-not-support-ng-options-how-to-pass-object/25256940#25256940

Answer (score 5):

`ng-click` won't work on datalist options, as the click event (nor any of the keypress events) doesn't seem to be fired when using the datalist.

You will have to use your `ng-change` on the function `input` and extend that to check if the current value is also present in the datalist.

Answer (score 2):

datalist is same as select, you don't put the event handler in option, you put the event handler in select or input.
Also you don't use ng-click, you use ng-change for this.

Comment: i put the event in datalist and not work..
here is en example
http://jsfiddle.net/lukers/MCnL2/

Comment: I said both ng-change, ng-model needs put in input or select, Do Not put in datalist or option.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input list="stateList"  name="state" ng-model = "payCntrl.billingAddressService.billingAddress.state">
    <datalist id="stateList">
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="state in payCntrl.billingAddressService.states | filter : {country : payCntrl.billingAddressService.billingAddress.country}" 
                                    value="{{state.name}}"></option>
       </select>    
   </datalist>
```

- The name and ng-model are on the input .

  Data :

  ```
  states : [{name : "NJ" , country: "USA"} ,  {name : "NY" , country: "USA"} , 
           {name : "GA" , country: "USA"} ,   {name : "TX" , country: "USA"} , 
           {name : "CA" , country: "USA"} , 
           {name : "Delhi" , country: "India"} ,  {name : "Karnataka" , country: "India"} , 
           {name : "Hyderabad" , country: "India"} ,  {name : "West Bengal" , country: "India"} , 
           {name : "Zhejiang" , country : "China"} , {name : "Hubei" , country : "China"},
           {name : "LONDON" , country : "United Kingdom"} , {name : "MANCHESTER" , country : "United Kingdom"}]
  ```