# html datalist not support ng-options: how to pass object

Tags: angularjs, html-datalist

I'm developing an app in mobile-angular-ui (angular+bootstrap).
In my login page, users can remember their credentials (username and password). Users' data ara saved in the localStorage.

That works fine. I can load users in my login page using datalist:

```
<form name="userForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail"
                           name="username" ng-model="user.username" list="UserMemoList"
                            required>
    </div>

    <datalist id="UserMemoList">
        <option ng-repeat="item in userMemoList track by $index" ng-click="setChange(item)"
                             value="{{item.username}}" >
        </option>
    </datalist>
```

I can select the item.username I want, but I'm not able to select the corresponding item.password.
My problem is that datalist doesn't work like select, and i cannot use ng-options. I have to use option+value to pass my value to the input.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine }">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword"
                           ng-model="user.password" required>
</div>
```

I would be able to use a ng-change="theSelectedUserIs(item)", but I'm not able to pass the item object, because datalist is related to the username input, so I need to pass item.username.

Any idea?
I don't want to use typeahead because actually is deprecated in bootstrap3 or add other libraries/js/css.
I would like to do that only using angular and html.

My controller:

```
$scope.userMemoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userList'));
var user = {};
LoginService.setUser(user);
```

userMemoList is an array of object like:
    {"username":"admin", "password":"admin"}, ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also pass with html data-id like so

---

### in your angular js file

```
// when input name textbox change, check the value is same with datalist value or not. If value same, then bind that item.password to angular password model.
$scope.$watch "user.username", (newValue) -> 
    if newValue != null && newValue.lenght > 0 
        $("#locationlist option").each (index) ->
            if $(this).val() == newValue
                $scope.user.password = $(this).data("id") // this line will set your password text field
```

---

### in your view

```
// pass user password via html5 (data-id) element like below
<datalist id="UserMemoList">
    <option ng-repeat="item in userMemoList track by $index" ng-click="setChange(item)"
                             value="{{item.username}}" "data-id" = {{item.password}} >
    </option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this problem in my app. Use  to wrap .

```
<input class="input form-control" placeholder="Search Conf by Application ID"
                                   list="app_ids" ng-model="confs_app_id"/></th>
                            <datalist id="app_ids">
                                <select>
                                    <option ng-repeat="app in app_list" value="{{app}}"></option>
                                </select>
                            </datalist>
```

Comment: I tried this, and in Safari it shows small <select> dropdowns under my search bar. It doesn't have this behavior in Firefox, Chrome, or Edge as far as I could tell.

Comment: datalist is not supported in safari.http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist