# Angular text field with dataList - Select option and call method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following setup

```
    <div>
      <label for='user' class="label-name">User</label>
      <input class="ref-input-field"
             id='user'
             type='text'
             placeholder="Search"
             ng-model="search"
             ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }"
             list="candidates"
             ng-selected="Detail.source_name"
             ng-change="searchForSource(search)"/>
      <datalist id="candidates" ng-model="name">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option ng-repeat="candidate in searchCandidates" value="{{ candidate.name }}" ng-click="selectUserSource(candidate)"></option>
      </datalist>
    </div>
```

JS Files

```
    $scope.selectUserSource = function(reference) {
        console.log('Reference Source Selected', reference);
    };

    $scope.searchForSource = function (term) {
        console.log('searchForRefSource', term);
        $meteor.call("findReferenceSource", term).then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            $scope.searchCandidates = resp;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

When I search for name I get the names populated in the dataList as expected. I want to be able to click on one of the names and have it call the selectReferenceSource() method. It does nothing now. The method is not called. I have tried ng-click and ng-change in the option line.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you share your `.js` file?

Comment: chrisz - Added entries from my JS file. Not much to them. I am just trying to console.log the chosen entry right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use angularjs ng-click with html5 datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340968/how-to-use-angularjs-ng-click-with-html5-datalist)